# How to create an async function in Fn project

Tags: fn

I am trying to create a FAAS in FN using Python. The problem is that I want my function to be executed asynchronously. I read in the [FN documentation](https://fnproject.io/tutorials/Async/) that this is possible by adding the following code to `func.yaml`.

```
type: async
```

But it didn't work! Apparently, `type: async` is not supported in new versions of Fn.

Another solution I found was using **Fn Flow**. But this package is no longer maintained and supported (based on it's [github page](https://github.com/fnproject/flow)).

Is there another way to make an asynchronous function in the fn project?
All I need is for the function to immediately return a response after being called and do its main work in another thread.

Comment: Based on this post from 2018 (https://medium.com/fnproject/fn-project-fn-server-api-v2-whats-new-a6c322a469a0), they did away with async functions in v2 of the API due to issues with scalability. But it doesn't say how to achieve the same effect in the latest version of fn.